# Ansible use Find Module on Registered Variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

My goal is to create a registered variable that I can use to search through and register other variables based on it.  Mostly it is a find module that is searching for files which then, based upon the filename, should be registered in other variables. Here is an example of what I have but it is not filtering out the variables properly:

```
- name: Register all files
  find:
    paths: ./files/
    patterns: '*.pkg,*.dmg'
    file_type: file
  register: installers
- name: Find Slack Installers
  find:
    paths: "{{ item }}"
    patterns: "*slack*"
  loop: "{{ installers.files|map(attribute='path')|map('basename')|list }}"
  register: slack_installers
- debug:
    msg: "{{ slack_installers }}"
```

This then outputs the following:

```
TASK [Find Slack Installers] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=slack.19.5.dmg)
ok: [localhost] => (item=slack.19.6.pkg)
ok: [localhost] => (item=box.1.2.3.dmg)
```

(ignore the versions of things, these are just fake names/versions but I'm just testing the find functionality)

As you can see the "Find Slack Installers" task is just registering everything within the "installers" variable rather than actually finding only things with the *slack* pattern.

EDIT FOR extended question:

```
set_fact:
  "{{ item.item|basename|lower }}_installers": "{{ installers.files|map(attribute='path')|map('basename')|list|select('search', '{{ item.item|basename|lower }}') }}"
loop: "{{ selected_installers.results }}"
loop_control:
  label: "{{ item.item|basename }}"
when: item.user_input == 'y' and
      item.item == ( item.item|basename )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `find` module twice in a row does not make sense.

*The [`find` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html) is to find files in a folder and its subfolders, but not to filter a list (even if file names are in this list), as you tried here. Have a look at the [examples for `find`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#examples) in the Ansible docs.*

However, you have two possibilities.

#### Using `find` with using the search word `slack` in pattern:

Add the search word `slack` directly as pattern in the `find` module: `*slack*.pkg,*slack*.dmg`.

```yaml
- name: Register all files
  find:
    paths: ./files/
    patterns: '*slack*.pkg,*slack*.dmg'
    file_type: file
  register: installers
- debug:
    msg: "{{ installers.files|map(attribute='path')|map('basename')|list }}"
```

*Result:*

```
TASK [Register all files] **************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "slack.19.5.dmg",
        "slack.19.6.pkg"
    ]
}
```

#### Using `find` to search only for the packages, then filtering your list:

Using `select('regex', 'slack')` you can filter the list by specific words in regex syntax, in your case specifying `slack` is enough.

```yaml
- name: Register all files
  find:
    paths: ./files/
    patterns: '*.pkg,*.dmg'
    file_type: file
  register: installers
- debug:
    msg: "{{ installers.files|map(attribute='path')|map('basename')|list|select('regex', 'slack') }}"
```

*Result:*

```
TASK [Register all files] **************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "slack.19.5.dmg",
        "slack.19.6.pkg"
    ]
}
```

---

#### EDIT: Extended Question

Nested jinja expressions are not allowed and not required.

If you want to specify a variable or a filter expression, just write it without using another jinja expression with `{{` and `}}`.

Try the following select:

```
select('search', item.item|basename|lower )
```

***Tip***

If you use several operators and are not sure which operator binds stronger, you can also use parentheses like in mathematics.
*The parenthesis should not be necessary at this point, but it does not interfere.*

```
select('search', (item.item|basename|lower) )
```

But if you want to get e.g. the second element (index=1) of your list, then the term looks like this:

```
( installers.files|map(attribute='path')|map('basename')|list )[1]
```

At this point, the parentheses are important so that the inner expression is evaluated first, and then the corresponding element can be accessed.

Comment: I understand it doesn't "make sense" but I guess I was trying to simplify this because i'm going to be "finding" a lot of these different installers.  I thought that registering all of the files once, then searching through the registered variable would make the most sense.  If not, I can just recreate the find with the search patterns.

Comment: That is correct. With the `select` variant you are generally a bit more flexible and can search the files once found by `find` also multiple times with different terms, if that should be necessary, without new operations on file system level.

Comment: I found a way to loop over the installers and get them to dynamically register the installers in a single task, but having a problem with the `select` filter and a looped variable.  Added in an edit in my original post

Comment: Look at the answer to your question in my post.

Comment: Thank you!! That fixed it! I had tried that before but with "" around the expression which must have messed it up.

Only thing i'm missing is being able to filter for both upper & lower case -- can't find a way to do that within the jinja2 filter, maybe I have to create a secondary variable to do that?  I was going to try with regex which worked properly before, but don't know how to grab the `item.item|basename` and pass it to a regex...

Comment: Figured it out! Adding "ignorecase=True" resolved it!

Comment: I would be very happy about an up-vote and if my answer provides the solution to your problem, I would be happy if you accept my answer. ([How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))